# How to properly implement AJAX into Django's MVT

Tags: python, django, ajax

**Estimated outcome:**

When a user visits *www.myapp.com/dashboard* Django shall `render` the dashboard. Meanwhile, AJAX shall call (on a regular period) the view `getAccountInfo` which queries data via the model `AccountInformation` from PostgreSQL database. The view then returns the latest data and AJAX/JS will update the DOM accordingly (staying on the very same page/url).

**What makes me feel dizzy:**
I just don't get how Ajax is implemented here considering the `Django MVT` architecture.

Basically each URL maps to a single view. So once I visit `/dashboard` it calls the view `render_Dashboard`. But when I now map the Ajax URL to that view and include the DB query logic into the very same view, it will render the complete site again which will create an infinite loop. So I have to map the Ajax URL to my second view to make it happen? But this view doesn't have an URL because I only want to have `/dashboard` as URL for users to visit? **So how to implement the second view into this architecture?**

What I have so far:

**views.py inside dashboard app:**

```
from Dashboard.models import AccountInformation

def getAccountInfo():
    account_information = serializers.serialize('json', AccountInformation.objects.all())
    print(account_information)
    return HttpResponse()

getAccountInfo()
```

**views.py inside project root:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def render_Dashboard(request, template="Dashboard_app.html"):
    return render(request, template)
```

**urls.py inside project root:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('Dashboard/', views.render_Dashboard, name='Dashboard')
]
```

**ajax part:**

```
var set_delay = 1000, // 1000ms = 1 second
    callout = function () {
        $.ajax('getAccountInfo/', {
                method: 'GET',
                async: "True",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(response){
                    var accountInfo = response;

                    profit = response[0].fields[0].account_profit
                    print(profit)

                    $("#runningPL").html(profit)
                }
        })
        .done(function (response) {
            // update the page
        })
        .always(function () {
            setTimeout(callout, set_delay);
        });
    };

// initial call
callout();
```

**Traceback:**

```
TypeError at /Dashboard/getAccountInfo/
getAccountInfo() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/Dashboard/getAccountInfo/
Django Version: 3.0
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
getAccountInfo() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
Exception Location: C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response, line 113
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Jonas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.0
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\Jonas\\Desktop\\Dashex',
 'C:\\Users\\Jonas\\Desktop\\Dashex',
 'C:\\Users\\Jonas\\Desktop\\Dashex',
 'C:\\Users\\Jonas\\Desktop\\Dashex\\Dashex',
 'C:\\Users\\Jonas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Jonas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Jonas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Jonas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38',
 'C:\\Users\\Jonas\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 4 Dec 2019 18:39:23 +0000
```

..when I put `self` as arg into the view function, it tells me `self` is not defined. If I then wrap the view into a class, I cannot import the class into the `urls.py`..

Comment: Your confusion is where you say the second view "doesn't have an URL". Of course it needs one, every request needs a URL. It might not be for use by the end user, but you need to have it if you want to request data from the backend.

Comment: So i can basically use whatever URL I want to since the end user won't see/notice it at all?

Comment: Sure, for example you might want to put it underneath /api/... or whatever.

Comment: Nice, thank you for your steady support, you helped me in like 10-15 SO posts I issued. Will definitely consider to propose you as `colleague of the week`!

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have an error `profit is not defined` within the Ajax part. When I print `profit` within the view it shows the correct value. Why can't Ajax grab the data?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying at all. Where is that variable supposed to be coming from in the JS?

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated the code in post

Comment: Well that is not real code, there is no `print` function in JS. Can you show the full error?

Comment: seems it is a Django related issue, posted above

Comment: All view functions need to take the `request` parameter.